# CRM Dynamics 2013 JavaScript Validate Minimum characters in free text field

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm-2013

I have a simple validation that I need to perform on the form where it forces the user to have a minimum amount of character in a field, I have the below code as follows, but it does not work, I tried it on load and on save event but no luck, please assist.

```
function TemsAndCondtitionsValidation()
{
 var TermsandCon = Xrm.Page.getAttribute("new_termsconditions").getValue();
 if(TermsandCon.value.length < 140)
  {
    Xrm.Utility.alertDialog("The length of characters entered are less than the minimum requirement of 140 characters");
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the form editor to attach this function to your onsave event:

```
function TemsAndCondtitionsValidation(context)
{
    var termsConds = Xrm.Page.getAttribute("new_termsconditions").getValue();
    if(termsConds.length < 140)   {
        Xrm.Utility.alertDialog("The length of characters entered are less than the minimum requirement of 140 characters");
        context.getEventArgs().preventDefault(); // cancel save
    }
}
```

Comment: This works fine and all, but now I am getting an error saying, Error: Unable to get property 'getEventArgs' of undefined or null reference.

Comment: Check your onsave registration in the form editor.  There's a checkbox for 'Pass execution context as first parameter' which should be checked, is it? (If it's not, don't forget you'll need to publish the change in order for it to take effect.)

Answer (score 0):

If `new_termsconditions` is of type text (either single or multiline) you could simply fix your code like this:

```
if(TermsandCon.length < 140)
```

Comment: Thanks Alex, where do I run this JS code, on load or on Save in CRM Form events?

Comment: It depends on your requirements